# Extracting time using beautiful soup with regular expressions

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I need help to come with the correct syntax when using beautiful Soup with regular expressions

I am using the code below to **scrape** only the time. The time is located in a DIV that includes a paragraph. The DIV and its content is shown below:

```
<div class="details"> 
    <p> $25 
    <br>
     8/23<br>
     7:00 pm 
     </p>                             
</div>
```

Code:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html = urlopen('https://place_holder/')
bs = BeautifulSoup(html.read(), 'html.parser')
for time_date in bs.find_all("div", {"class": "details"}):
    print(time_date.text)
```

When I run the above code I am getting the following results.

```
$25 
8/23
7:00 pm
```

Because I only want to extract the time (7:00 pm) I would like to use regular expressions to do that. I could not come with the correct syntax that works. I hope that someone can help me.

Comment: You might want to add the `regex` tag to your question

Answer (score 3):

There's no need of regular expressions here. BeautifulSoup can get you the data you need. Just access the last element of the `<p>` tag using `.contents[-1]`.

```
for time_date in bs.find_all("div", {"class": "details"}):
    print(time_date.p.contents[-1].strip())
# 7:00 pm
```

The `.contents` of a tag looks like this:

```
[' $25 \n    ', <br/>, '\n     8/23', <br/>, '\n     7:00 pm \n     ']
```

If you *need* to use RegEx, you can use this:

```
for time_date in bs.find_all("div", {"class": "details"}):
    print(re.findall(r'\d+:\d+ [ap]m', time_date.text)[0])
```

Comment: Thank you Keyur. I would like also to find out how I do it with regular expressions. Can you show me.

Comment: second `\d+` is probably always 2 digit.

Comment: @Menachem is there the possibility of 24 h format, which wouldn't work with `[ap]m`

Comment: Thanks again. How do I actually incorporate this expression into the code? Your reply is highly appreciated because I will be using regular expressions in other similar cases  and I could not find the correct syntax to code it using the compile statement. Your previous solution without the regular expressions worked well.

Comment: @Menachem check the `re` package in python